# Flash CS4 How do you set variable to the Object Dragging Collison?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, collision, inventory, cs4

I am doing a game for my computer science class and I am working on inventory, dragging an item into it.  I do not know how to set the item as whatever the user clicked to drag.

At the moment I hard coded it to the item they are dragging, but in the future I want more items, so a variable set to the item they are dragging would make it work perfectly, but I don't know what it's called to do that.

Here is my code for inventory item dragging

```
function dragItem (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    knife_loot.startDrag();
}

function dropItem (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    knife_loot.stopDrag();

    if ((knife_loot.hitTestObject(inv_game)) && (inv_game.visible == true))
    {
        trace("Item dropped in inventory")
        trace("")

        knife_loot.x = 80
        knife_loot.y = 120
    }
}

// end of dragging and dropping items
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with:

```
// List the items you want to drag.
var aList:Array = [knife_loot, spoon_loot, fork_loot];

// InteractiveObject is superclass for SimpleButton, Sprite and MovieClip.
// If you're sure what they all are then just use their class instead.
for each (var anItem:InteractiveObject in aList)
{
    // Subscribe them all for dragging.
    anItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDrag);
}

public var draggedItem:InteractiveObject;

function onDrag(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // Use e.currentTarget because original MouseEvent e.target
    // could be something from deep inside of top object e.currentTarget.
    draggedItem = e.currentTarget as InteractiveObject;
    draggedItem.startDrag();

    // Let's hook drop events.
    stage.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, onDrop);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onDrop);
}

function onDrop(e:Event):void
{
    // Unhook drop events.
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, onDrop);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onDrop);

    // Drop the item.
    draggedItem.stopDrag();

    if ((draggedItem.hitTestObject(inv_game)) && (inv_game.visible == true))
    {
        trace("Item", draggedItem.name, "was dropped to inventory.");
        trace("");

        draggedItem.x = 80;
        draggedItem.y = 120;
    }

    // Forget the item.
    draggedItem = null;
}
```